# Problema con Navigation Drawer (consulta)

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, navigationview

Estoy adentrándome en Android Studio y necesito que me saquen una duda.

Por un lado tengo un `Activity` que dentro suyo tiene 2 `fragment`(`Data` y `Details`) donde el 2do reacciona dependiendo lo que se seleccione en el primero.

Por el otro lado tengo un `Navigation Drawer`, que según tengo entendido utiliza solo `fragments` por lo cual no puedo insertarle dentro el `activity` antes mencionado. Como podría hacer para vincular estas 2 partes?

Intente crear un `Fragment(Container)` que dentro tenga a `Data` y `Details` pero al llamarlo desde el `NavigationActivity` me da error. Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pasale los otros fragment de forma dinamica!

**Este es el codigo:**

```js
FragmentTransaction transaction;
                    Nombre_fragment fragment = new Nombre_fragment();
                                           transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.El Drawer, *fragment*);
                   transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
```